# настройка VirtualHosta

Tags: apache2, virtual-hosts

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: VirtualHost]
ошибка
Status Code: 404; Not Found
никак не могу настроить  apache  .два dotnet core 3.1 приложения.каждый имеет свой kestrel-*.service.по одному работают.вместе работает только тот который первый.
обратите внимание на логи
первый lockalhost всё забирает
я  может не корректно ставлю вопрос,но мне нужна ваша помощь

Answer (score 0):

нашел ответ.Прописал разные порты и прописал в файле /etc/apache2/port.conf
Listen "port"
https://www.tecmint.com/change-apache-port-in-linux/